# Internet cuts out on all devices connected for a short moment

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, bittorrent

This is my first time on this site so please be nice. Ok so, I'll try to make this short and sweet

- didnt have internet for 4 months just got it back the end of last month
- my "dish" the thing that sends the signal to the tower was not lit up and had slow internet from the begining it is now lit up but is still kinda slow
- I do live in the mountains with lots of trees maybe that has something to do with it
- like an idiot I tried to torrent a program with utorrent and when the file downloaded I got scared and deleted it off my laptop same with the utorrent

Im scared that I downloaded a virus or something but I didnt open it well anyways...I ran the windows defender a million times with full scans and quick scans and all say that its clean but what happens is Ill be on my phone connected to the wifi and it will get really slow then it will says something like cant dns server, timed out, or something else I cant remember very good I use chrome dont know if that needs to be said or not but yeah...
Also I bought a new computer I guess its called a "super computer" but what if the internet has a virus! I dont really know I just want some other peoples imput. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're worried about nothing important, stress less. Unless you ran whatever you downloaded before you deleted it, its incredibly unlikely you have contracted a virus from it.

Secondly, modern day viruses don't typically aim to deny services to you. They aim to be more sneaky, sitting there and collecting data and sending it back to the creator. If their sole purpose was to deny you services to the point where you got upset, you'd probably buy a new computer or format the existing one, defeating any real purpose of making a virus.

Thirdly,

> what if the internet has a virus

That's not really possible the way you're thinking it is. The internet isn't a device on your network which can be infected like a computer or phone etc.

What you're experiencing by the sound of it based on

> dns server, timed out,

is simply performance related to your internet connection. You're getting timeouts or DNS errors because your router can't connect to your ISP properly and the connection can't get a response in a reasonable amount of time, hence 'timeout'.

You're best off contacting your ISP to sort out your connection woes, and stop fretting about uTorrent having possibly given you a virus!